# Storing big data structure in saveInstanceState bundle

Tags: java, android, optimization

I've read that if we want to save any data when activity is restarting (rotating device), we have to store all data in Bundle's `saveInstanceState()`.

But, if we want to save big data structure in bundle - it freezes system and increases memory usage.

For example:
I have a `HashMap` of 50,000,000 elements. The reading is from SD card. So, if I save `HashMap` to `Bundle` - it freezes the rotation of device for a very loooooong time.

Is there a way, in which we can save data without storing in `Bundle`? (save the pointer to `HashMap` for example?)

Comment: Interesting. If each key is 1 byte and they all map to null, this is already an OutOfMemoryError on most devices. I think a database would be a good place for that data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You definitely shouldn't do this.  You should handle orientation changes manually or keep this data out of your activity, like in a Service.

Comment: Thanks, I don't think about service, but it will be very useful for my application.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in Java there are no pointers, only references. The only one`HashMap` is not a problem though, the problem is in saving 50,000,000 elements which it contains. If you really want to do this you can optimize reading/writing from files, check [this](http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2008/02/java_tip_how_read_files_quickly).

But you shouldn't optimize this. As Donald Knuth said:

> Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

You should write handling the screen rotations, to not have to save and load such a big data during the rotation.